# Clarification for verses 40-46 in Chapter 10 of Shiva Geeta

Tags: shiva, gita, shiva-gita

In [Shiva Geeta Chapter 10](http://www.mahapashupatastra.com/2010/05/shiva-gita-ch-10-jeeva-swaroopa.html), Verses 40-46 speak of Jiva Swaroop and Atman and Paramatma in the following way:

> For the Jiva, in the wakeful state when the enjoyments of Karmas decline, moving away from the gross body and outside indiriyas (organs), it reaches the swapnavastha (dream state) and with desire of enjoying the karmas in dreams, as like as a magician assumes various forms, this Jiva transitions from one state to another. Jiva remains entangled with Vasanas (desires), but the self-illuminating Atman always remains untouched with them. Due to the Vasanas of the Antahkarana, Jiva becomes bound. Due to the existence of Vasanas of the Antahkarana the Paramatma remains as their witnesser. Because of the existence of Vasanas, this entire universe which is supported (and originates) on the basis of Karmas gets projected. Like the wakeful state, in the dream state also this universe which is of the form of Vasanas appears as the doer-task-action. Atman remains as the witness of all the actions performed by the mind and remains as self-illuminating power.

Can anyone elaborate a little on *moving away from the gross body and outside indiriyas (organs), it reaches the swapnavastha (dream state) and with desire of enjoying the karmas in dreams, as like as a magician assumes various forms, this Jiva transitions from one state to another* and on the distinction between Jiva and Atman?